# Expectation value in a mixed state of two distinguishable spin-$1/2$ particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, density-operator

> Consider two *distinguishable* spin-$1/2$ particles in a state with
>   total spin $S=1$, described by the density matrix
>   $$\rho=\frac{1}{3}\left[\left|11\right\rangle\left\langle11\right|+\left|10\right\rangle\left\langle10\right|+\left|1-1\right\rangle\left\langle1-1\right|\right]$$
>   in the $\left\{\left|S,S_z\right\rangle\right\}$ basis. Calculate the expectation value $$\left\langle S^{(1)}_z
>  S^{(2)}_z\right\rangle,$$ where $S^{(i)}_z$ is the $z$-component of
>   the spin operator of particle $i$.

Since $$\rho\doteq\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}1&&&\\&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$S^{(1)}_z S^{(2)}_z=\left(\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)^2\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z\doteq\frac{\hbar^2}{4}\begin{pmatrix}1&&&\\&-1&&\\&&-1&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix},$$ should I get $$\left\langle S^{(1)}_z
 S^{(2)}_z\right\rangle=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\rho S^{(1)}_z
 S^{(2)}_z\right)=-\frac{\hbar^2}{6}\,?$$ I'm not sure, since $\rho$ is in the $\left\{\left|S,S_z\right\rangle\right\}$ basis, while $S^{(1)}_z S^{(2)}_z$ is in the $\left\{\left|S^{(1)}_z,S^{(2)}_z\right\rangle\right\}$ basis.

Comment: As you point out, if you want to use the matrix representation of the operators, you should use the same basis for all of them. Using the expressions for the triplet and singlet in both bases you can deduce the matrix representation of $S^{(1)}_z S^{(2)}_z$ in the $\{S,S_z\}$ basis.

Comment: @secavara, is there an intrinsic way to avoid using the matrix representation of operators? Or is this the only way you can find?

Comment: In a way we almost always end up using some form of representation when it comes to specific exercises. Even when we write operators in the form $\sum_n \, c_n \, | \psi_n \rangle \langle \psi_n |$ we are selecting a basis $\{|\psi_n\rangle\}$, because ultimately this is just an alternative way of writing the matrix representation. For instance, you can write in this case $S_z^{(1)}S_z^{(2)}= \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \left[ |11\rangle \langle 11| + ... \right]$ and compute the trace contracting the bras, kets, but this is practically not distinct from computing the matrices, multiplying and tracing.

Comment: Something you can do close to what you want: For the Hilbert space of two spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particles you have $S_z^{(1)} S_z^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2} \left[S_z^2 - (S_z^{(1)})^2-(S_z^{(2)})^2 \right]=\frac{1}{2} S_z^2 - \frac{1}{4} \hbar^2 \, \mathbf{1}.$ Hence you have $\langle S_z^{(1)} S_z^{(2)} \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}[\rho S_z^2]- \frac{1}{4} \hbar^2.$ But again, for the remaining trace one resorts to the $S,S_z$ representation. For instance, you can notice that in this case $\rho = \frac{1}{6 \hbar^2} S^2$ and then find $\mathrm{Tr}[S^2 S_z^2]=2\hbar^2\times(\hbar^2+\hbar^2)$.